# Integrate by substitution (Not by parts) $\int(x^2-2x)(x^3-3x^2+9)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have an integration question and I cannot figure out why my answer is incorrect as online calculators will use integration by parts instead, when technically we haven't (and won't) learn that method so I want to be very comfortable with integration with substitution.

$$\int\big(x^2-2x\big)\big(x^3-3x^2+9\big)dx$$

So what I did was
$$u=x^3-3x^2+9$$

$$=\int(x^2-2x)\;u\;\frac{dx}{3(x^2-2x)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{3} \int u \;du $$

$$=\frac{u^2}{6}$$

$$=\frac{\big(x^3-3x^2+9\big)^2}{6}+C$$

But apparently this is incorrect.

My problem may be misunderstanding what can be substituted when?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Apparently this is correct.

Comment: Though it's probably a pain in the rear, you could just multiply the polynomials out. Granted, probably not the most efficient method.

Comment: You can verify your answer by differentiation. It is correct.

Comment: Hm. @OP - What was the answer offered?

Comment: Hm that's odd. My bad I should of checked it by using differentiation. Symbolab gave me $\frac{x^6}{3}-\frac{x^6}{6}-x^5+3x^4-\frac{3x^4}{2}+3x^3-9x^2$ Which apparently is not equal to my answer but I'm not sure and they may be equivalent.

Comment: Symbolab's ugly answer is equivalent to yours. The two answers just differ by a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as a 'chain rule backwards'.

If you set up the situation

$$\int f'(x)f(x)dx$$
it will equal
$$\frac{\big(f(x)\big)^{2}}{2}+c$$

So, a small adjustment sets up the situation,
$$\int\big(x^2-2x\big)\big(x^3-3x^2+9\big)dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\int\big(3x^2-6x\big)\big(x^3-3x^2+9\big)dx$$
and the answer is then,
$$=\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{\big(x^3-3x^2+9\big)^2}{2}+c$$
which is the same as you got.

It's illuminating to now differentiate this answer using the 'chain rule' to see how the one part answer goes back to the two parts of the question.

The advantage of the 'chain rule backwards' approach is that, although harder to learn initially, lets you see the 'bigger picture' whereas the substitution method tends to focus eyes on the 'smaller picture' of getting a technical mechanism to work.

Anyway, don't lose sight of the fact that you got it right !

PS

The more general rule is,
$$\int f'(x)(f(x))^ndx$$
$$=\frac{\big(f(x)\big)^{n+1}}{n+1}+c$$
In your case $n=1$.

Comment: Woah thanks heaps, that's interesting. Why does it become $(3x^2-\frac{3}{2}x)$? Because you pulled out the constant 1/3 to make the first bracket equal the derivative of the second correct?

Comment: I call it the fiddle factor. You look at what the derivative of $()$ would be. If a simple multiplication by a constant adjusts what is multiplying $f(x)$ gets you it, then go ahead and adjust to get $′()$ and put the reciprocal of that constant outside the integration. You haven't changed the essence of the question because, in your case, 13×3=1. It can only be done with a number, of course; you can't pull  out of the integration. It's far harder to write down than do! I'll add the more general rule to my answer in a moment. (A green tick if you like the answer would be marvellous!)

Comment: But $dy/dx=x^3-3x^2+9$ is equal to $3x^2-6x$?

Comment: Yes ! I'll run through the thought process; $f(x)=x^3-3x^2+9$ so $f'(x)=3x^2-6x$. So you'd like to have $3x^2-6x$ multiplying $f(x)$ but you look and see that the question only has $x^2-2x$ where you'd like  $3x^2-6x$. Then you spot that if you multiply that $x^2-2x$ by 3 you get what you want, the $3x^2-6x$. However you can't just randomly multiply by 3, unless, somewhere else, you divide by 3. The somewhere else is to put the divide by 3 'outside' the integration altogether. It is sneaky but it works because it's OK to pull number factors out of integrations. Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: Apologies, I've spotted the typo that's causing your comment question and changed it. Sorry !

Comment: Yes, makes perfect sense now! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine. There is more than one way to solve a problem.

Here are some minor edit.

Let $u=x^3-3x^2+9$

$\int(x^2-2x)\cdot (x^3-3x^2+9)dx$

$=\int(x^2-2x)\cdot u\frac{d\color{blue} u}{3(x^2-2x)}$

=$\frac{1}{3} \int udu $

$=\frac{u^2}{6}+\color{blue}{C}$

=$\frac{(x^3-3x^2+9)^2}{6}+C$

Comment: Thank you very much for that. Silly mistake with the dx. Is it always correct practice to write +C after you integrate or can you just whack it on at the end?

Comment: i usually write it after I remove the indefinite integral sign to indicate the presence of an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, you can always expand:

$$\int\big(x^2-2x\big)\big(x^3-3x^2+9\big)dx$$
$$= \int x^5-3x^4+9x^2-2x^4+6x^3-18x \  \mathrm{d} x$$
$$= \int x^5-5x^4+6x^3+9x^2-18x \  \mathrm{d} x$$
$$= \frac{1}{6}x^6 - x^5 + \frac{3}{2}x^4 + 3x^3-9x^2 + C$$
$$= \frac{1}{6} \left(x^6 - 6x^5 + 9x^4 + 18x^3 - 54x^2 + C'\right)$$

Which should be equivalent to:
$$\frac{1}{6}  \left( \left(x^3-(3x^2-9) \right)\left(x^3-(3x^2-9) \right)  \right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{6} \left(x^6-2(x^3)(3x^2-9) + (3x^2-9)^2 \right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{6} \left(x^6-6x^5+18x^3+9x^4-54x^2+81 \right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{6} \left(x^6-6x^5+9x^4+18x^3-54x^2+C' \right) \color{#228b22}{\checkmark}$$